# Add div with (contents and attributes)

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#container").add("div").html("Hello");
```

This line kinda messed up and changed the html on the #container, or well it didn't do what I intended at least.

I am looking to add a div with different attributes and value (html?) in a container div, descendant.

Not really sure how I can just modify that new div I want to add with these attributes and values I need? How?

Comment: What would really help is if you told us precisely what attributes, and/or properties, you wanted to set.

Answer (score 1):

So why not just?

```
$("#container").append("<div>Hello</div>");
```

or else:

```
var $div = $(document.createElement("div"))
           .attr( attributeKey, attributeValue )
           .prop( propertyKey, propertyValue )
           .text("Hello");
$("#container").append($div);
```

**Note:** Use `$(document.createElement("div"))` over `$("<div></div>")` because it is slightly faster.

Comment: Or the even shorter version: `$('<div />')`

Answer (score 0):

```
var newDiv = $('<div></div>');
newDiv.attr('id', 'myId');
newDiv.html('Hello World!');

$('#container').append(newDiv);
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/DDnck/)

Answer (score 0):

My own suggestion would be:

```
$('<div />', {
    'text' : 'Hello world',
    'class' : 'newDiv',
    'click' : function (){
        console.log('You clicked the newly-added div');
    },
    'contentEditable' : true
}).appendTo('#container');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/77GX2/).

If, however, you'd like to add HTML to the newly-created element, use `'html'` in place of `'text'`:

```
$('<div />', {
    'html' : '<em>more text</em>',
    'class' : 'newDiv',
    'click' : function (){
        console.log('You clicked the newly-added div');
    },
    'contentEditable' : true
}).appendTo('#container');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/77GX2/1/).